# Heat exchanger with stationary fluid on one side

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have a problem where water is heated using solar energy.(link to the question is posted below) The water is stationary in a tank, and oil is used to transfer the heat from the solar pannel to the water tank. I'm given the oil mass flow rate and initial temperature and the power from the solar pannel which I used to calculate the temperature of the oil exiting the solar plate and entering the heat exchanger. I'm also given the mass of water in the tank and its temperature, as well as the surface area of the heat exchanger and the heat transfer coefficient.

The question asks for the time required for the water in the tank to reach a certain temperature.

My problem is I don't have either of the exit temperatures (of water and oil). I searched on how to obtain that, and there is a method called the NTU (method) but it is normally used when both the fluids are flowing, and I'm not sure what kind of flow to consider this one, since one of the fluids is stationary.

I found the problem on chegg (although answered totally wrong).

https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/schematic-diagram-water-heater-using-solar-energy-shown--oil-circulated-closed-circuit-usi-q42247052

Comment: Can you use a very slow velocity for the water.  Maybe .0001 mm/hr

Comment: Not sure if that would work this would make the mass flow rate very small, and also I still wouldn't know which type of flow it is.

Comment: Let's see your setup of the problem so far.  To start with, what is the initial  temperature of the oil coming out of the solar panel?

Comment: Assuming $c_{oil} = 2000 J/kgK$ then it would be 26.25 C

Comment: @Peter, your tank should be insulated (the problem didn't state this).

Comment: To do this problem properly, you need to know the mass of oil in the solar collector.

Comment: If the mass of oil in the solar collector is negligible, all the solar heat goes into the water, irrespective of the oil flow rate.

Comment: See the ADDENDUM in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint.  If we assume that the residence time of oil in the heat exchanger is short, then we can regard the water temperature as nearly constant during the time it takes for a parcel of oil to pass through the exchanger.  Under this assumption, the heat balance on the oil passing through the heat exchange is:
$$\dot{m}C\frac{dT}{dA}=-h(T-T_w)$$where $\dot{m}$ is the mass flow rate of oil, C is the oil heat capacity, T is the oil temperature, dA is the differential area, and h is the heat transfer coefficient.  The solution to this equation is:
$$\frac{(T_{out}-T_w)}{(T_{in}-T_w)}=\exp{\left(-\frac{hA}{\dot{m}C}\right)}$$

**ADDENDUM**

If we let $T_1$ represent the temperature of the oil exiting the solar collector and entering the heat exchanger and $T_2$ represent the temperature of the oil exiting the heat exchanger and entering the solar collector, then, with these parameter definitions, the previous equation becomes:  $$\frac{(T_{2}-T_w)}{(T_{1}-T_w)}=\exp{\left(-\frac{hA}{\dot{m}C}\right)}\tag{1}$$

If the oil holdup in the solar collector is negligible (i.e., it has negligible thermal inertia), the heat balance on the solar collector becomes simply:  $$\dot{m}C(T_1-T_2)=\dot{Q}\tag{2}$$where $\dot{Q}$ represents the solar heating rate in the collector.  If we solve Eqns. 1 and 2 for $T_1$ and $T_2$, we obtain:
$$T_1=T_w+\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{m}C}\frac{1}{1-e^{-\xi}}\tag{3a}$$
$$T_2=T_w+\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{m}C}\frac{e^{-\xi}}{1-e^{-\xi}}\tag{3b}$$where $\xi=\frac{hA}{\dot{m}C}$

The overall heat balance on the heat exchanger is given by:
$$M_WC_W\frac{dT_w}{dt}=-\dot{m}C(T_1-T_2)\tag{4}$$
Combining Eqns. 3 and 4 gives simply$$M_WC_W\frac{dT_w}{dt}=\dot{Q}\tag{5}$$Therefore, we have, finally, $$T_w=T_{w0}+\frac{\dot{Q}t}{M_wC_W}\tag{5a}$$
$$T_1=T_{w0}+\frac{\dot{Q}t}{M_wC_W}+\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{m}C}\frac{1}{1-e^{-\xi}}\tag{5b}$$
$$T_2=T_{w0}+\frac{\dot{Q}t}{M_wC_W}+\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{m}C}\frac{e^{-\xi}}{1-e^{-\xi}}\tag{5c}$$

**ADDENDUM 2**

This addendum extends the previous analysis to include the holdup and associated thermal inertia of the oil in the heat exchanger (while omitting the thermal inertia of the heat exchanger itself, which is unspecified and unknown).  The holdup of the oil in the collector is still neglected, since there is no detail whatsoever provided on this.  So the only oil holdup included is in the heat exchanger.

The heat balance on the oil passing through the collector is again:
$$\dot{m}C(T_1-T_2)=\dot{Q}\tag{6}$$

If we assume that the oil passing through the heat exchange is well-mixed axially, the heat balance for the oil passing through the heat exchange is given by:  $$M_OC_O\frac{dT_2}{dt}=\dot{m}C(T_1-T_2)-hA(T_2-T_w)\tag{7}$$
where $T_2$ is both the well-mixed temperature of the oil in the heat exchanger and the exit oil temperature from the heat exchanger.

The heat balance on the water in the heat exchanger is given by:  $$M_WC_W\frac{dT_w}{dt}=hA(T_2-T_w)\tag{8}$$If we combine Eqns. 6 and 7, we obtain:  $$M_OC_O\frac{dT_2}{dt}=\dot{Q}-hA(T_2-T_w)\tag{9}$$Initial conditions for Eqns. 8 and 9 are $T_2=T_W=T_0$ at t = 0, where $T_0=25\ C$.  The mass of oil in the heat exchanger can be calculated from $$M_O=\rho_OV=\rho_On\frac{\pi D^2}{4}L=\rho_O(n\pi D L)\frac{D}{4}=\rho_OA\frac{D}{4}$$where n is the number of heat exchange tubes.  From the data in the problem statement, if we use a typical value of 0.8 gm/cc for the density of the heat transfer oil, we obtain a value of the oil holdup equal to $M_O=400\ gm=0.4\ kg$.  This means that the residence time of the oil in the heat exchange is about 1 sec.

The analytic solution to Eqns. 8 and 9 for the temperature of the water as a function of time is given by:  $$T_W=T_0+\frac{\dot{Q}t}{M_WC_W}\left[1-\frac{(1-e^{-t/\tau})}{(t/\tau)}\right]\tag{10}$$where $\tau$ is given by the equation $$\frac{1}{\tau}=hA\left[\frac{1}{M_WC_W}+\frac{1}{M_OC_O}\right]$$

I leave it to the OP to determine the value of t from this equation that results in a water temperature of 50 C.

Comment: The only problem is that we can calculate the speed of the oil and the length of the heat exchanger, thus we can calculate the time spent by the oil in the heat exchanger and so it is not negligible. Also, does this neglect the temperature gradient inside the heat exchanger or is the effect captured by the differential equation?

Comment: Usually, except for liquid metals, axial heat conduction is negligible.  But your point about the finite mass holdup in the heat exchange is valid.  Still, we don't take into account the thermal inertia of the heat exchanger itself.  Including both the thermal inertia of the oil holdup in the heat exchanger and advective transport along the heat exchange tubes makes this a much more complicated problem.  Maybe they intended for you to assume that there is intimate axial mixing along the tube so that the temperature doesn't vary along the length?

Comment: See ADDENDUM 2 to see the result of including oil holdup in the heat exchanger.

Comment: Did you have any questions or comments about the approach and results presented in Addendum #2?